# change: function (event, ui) to uncheck a checked checkbox in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I made a simple script in Jquery which has a range of text-boxes with auto-completes.
When a value is selected from an auto complete,then the corresponding check box with the same ID as the auto complete value,will be selected.
The selection part is working perfectly,how ever I am trying to work out how to unchecked a selected check-box when the value of an auto-complete changes.I can detect the change but I am unsure how to unselected a check-box.

Here is my code.

```
  $(function () {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC",
        "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang",
        "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp",
        "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme", "eewjdskjuwwe"];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            var txtbx1 = (ui.item.value);
            $("#tags").val(txtbx1);
            var tags = $("#tags").val(txtbx1);
            var checkboxval = "";
            checkboxval = tags.val();
            //alert($(tags).val());
            $("#" + checkboxval + "").prop("checked", true);

        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            alert(checkboxval);
        }
    });
```

I know it has something to do with this line of code but I'm a bit stuck.Where am I going wrong? Here is the link to my JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/13/

```
  change: function (event, ui) {
            alert(checkboxval);
        }
```

EDIT: Here is the working solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/22/

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that the `checkboxval` variable doesn't exist in `change:`

If you copy down the code used to find the `checkboxval` variable, you'll have better luck.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? Can we provide you with more help?

Comment: Hi Shafig,
I'm still a bit stuck.I have tried to follow your advice but can't seem to get it to work yet.
This is my solution so far http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/19/

Comment: Got it working.I made a global variable which can be accessed inside of another function.
Here is the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/22/
Now I just need to work out how to get the change function not to fire the first time a value is put into the textbox.

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to have a counter that you increment every time a value is entered, but only fire the event on greater than zero.

Comment: @LaurieWilliams Is there a particular reason that you don't need the change event to fire the first time? Maybe there is a better solution to this that we can work out. Also, it seems that you don't actually need the change event at all, you just need to deselect the currently selected checkbox, and then select the new one, which can all be done from inside the select function's code.

Comment: Hi @Shafiq Jetha,
I am probably going about it the wrong way.
I'm still working on it and I have tried to add a function to detect if a change is made and it sort of works but I still don't have it working properly because I think I have over complicated it.What is your suggestion?Here is my solution so far : http://jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/26/
I will update this again when I have this working properly.

Comment: @LaurieWilliams I think you might want to try using the 'data-' HTML5 attribute to get around this. Try this instead: Set the 'data-name' property on each input box, then change that when a new name is entered. At this time too, you can check all of the 'data-name' properties and check those ones. Check the data- HTML5 property text and examples to get a better understanding of how to get this to work.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as so. I'm glad you were able to get there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.I made a global variable which can be accessed inside of another function. Here is the solution : jsfiddle.net/lauriewilliams/45yQH/22 Now I just need to work out how to get the change function not to fire the first time a value is put into the textbox.